# Customize PKToolPicker tools

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, pencilkit, ipados13

`PKToolPicker` in PencilKit (iOS 13+) comes with default tools that are pen, marker, pencil, eraser, lasso, ruler and color pickers on iOS. on iPadOS this is extended with undo/redo and a `(...)` menu that provides an "auto minimize" option for the PKToolPicker.

Two questions:

- Is there anyway to *disable/remove* one of the default tools (say Ruler) in the Picker?
- Is it possible to add other actions in the `(...)` sub-menu (this is the case in the Snapshot controller with lots of interesting options)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2):

I do see in the PKToolPicker help you can remove the Ruler by using

isRulerActive: BOOL so stating it as a False should do the trick.

As for add other actions not seeing anything. Maybe IOS 15

Comment: isRulerActive indicates if the Ruler Tool is active on the screen or not. It does not show/side the Ruler Tool in the PKTools.